# Please recommend performance testing tool for MySQL under Ubuntu/Debian

Tags: mysql, performance, ubuntu, benchmarking, load-testing

I would like to test performance of my MySQL MyISAM and InnoDB engines under Debian or Ubuntu Server for CPU and memory consumption. I need to simulate many concurrent reads, writes and updates. I can set up a separate isolated environment similar to my production server to perform the tests.

Answer (score 9):

For Debian, [sysbench](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-benchmark-your-system-cpu-file-io-mysql-with-sysbench) is hard to beat. It's a simple 1-2-3:

1. Install

   `sudo apt-get install sysbench`
2. Prepare

   `sysbench --test=oltp --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-db=test --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=yourrootsqlpassword prepare`
3. Benchmark

   `sysbench --test=oltp --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-db=test --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=yourrootsqlpassword --max-time=60 --oltp-read-only=on --max-requests=0 --num-threads=8 run`

Comment: `mysql -u root -p` and `create database test` might be good additions to this answer

Comment: I think the `prepare` command does exactly that - create the test database. At least that's what is documented on https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-benchmark-your-system-cpu-file-io-mysql-with-sysbench: "To measure MySQL performance, we first create a test table in the database test with 1,000,000 rows of data"

Comment: @goetz sysbench 0.4.12 does not create the database itself.

Comment: @mfnalex Thanks - I haven't tested it, just looked at the documentation. I probably misinterpreted "To measure MySQL performance, we first create a test table in the database test with 1,000,000 rows of data" on https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-benchmark-your-system-cpu-file-io-mysql-with-sysbench

Comment: FATAL: Cannot find benchmark 'oltp': no such built-in test, file or module

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter would also work using Jdbc sampler.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL Workbench should do.

http://wb.mysql.com/

Comment: MySQL Workbench only measures performance for MySQL versions 5.6.6 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : http://osdb.sourceforge.net/